# Instance method clashes with static method

Tags: apex, class, method, inner-class

I am working with Apex inner classes and I got the limitation described below

I can't name a method in my inner class with the same name I used in a static method in the containing class

When I do that I got this error

**myClass.myInnerClass: Instance method clashes with static method: myMethod(): from: myClass**

*Code example*

```
public class MyClass{
    public static void myMethod(){
        // outer myMethod code
    }

    public class MyInnerClass{
        public void myMethod(){
            // inner myMethod code
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand the clashes between the two methods, because from what I know

The outer method can be called like this : `MyClass.myMethod()`

The inner method can be called like this : `(new MyClass.MyInnerClass()).myMethod()`

Do you have more info about this limitation of the language **?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these two valid examples:

method1() is a static method on the outer class:

```
public class Example{
  public static void method1(){
    system.debug('static method');
  }
  public class innerClass{
    public innerClass(){
      method1();
    }
  }
}
```

method1() is an instance method on the inner class:

```
public class Example{
  public class innerClass{
    public void method1(){
      system.debug('instance method');
    }
    public innerClass(){
      method1();
    }
  }
}
```

When creating an instance of the inner class:

```
new Example.innerClass();
```

The class constructor works in each case, and is able to successfully call `method1()`, logging `static method` and `instance method` respectively.

But what if the class had both the static and instance methods with the same signature? Which `method1()` would be called in the constructor?

It's this ambiguity that prevents the compiler from allowing static and instance methods from having the same signature.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, In my case the instance method is in the innerClass, if I want to call it from the containing class constructor I have to instantiate the innerClass so why there is clash?

Comment: Inner classes can call static methods on their containing class. I'll make that more clear in my examples.